# Safe way to compare dates (time_t)

Tags: c++, c

I was trying to write a portable function that checks if a date is inside a range I wrote this implementation but doesn't work:

```
/**
 * @brief teIsDateInRange checks if a date is inside a range of dates
 *        teIsDateRange checks if date is in [firstDate, endDate]
 * @param firstDate first date of the range
 * @param lastDate last date of the range
 * @param date date to check
 * @return 0 if the date is in the range, 1 if date is greater then lastDate or
 *         -1 if date is less than firstDate
 */
TMEXT_API int TMEXT_CALL teIsDateInRange( time_t firstDate, time_t lastDate, time_t date )
{
    const auto diff1 = std::difftime( firstDate, date );

    if ( diff1 > 0.0 ) return -1;
    if ( diff1 == 0.0 ) return 0;

    // we are sure that date is greater then firstDate now check upper range
    const auto diff2 = std::difftime( date, lastDate );
    if ( diff2 >= 0.0 ) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

I've wrote a simple test suite but test fails

```
// main.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE timeext_test_unit
#include <timeext/timeext.h>            // function where is defined teIsDateInRange

#include <utility/diagnostic.h>
// stop warnings on mingw with boost 1.55.0
GCC_DIAG_STOP
GCC_DIAG_OFF(unused-local-typedefs)
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
GCC_DIAG_START

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( test_suite1 )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_case1 )
{
    const time_t first = time( nullptr );
    const time_t last = first + 500;
    const time_t d1 = first - 50;
    const time_t d2 = first + 40;
    const time_t d3 = first + 600;

    const auto r1 = teIsDateInRange( first, last, d1 );
    const auto r2 = teIsDateInRange( first, last, d2 );
    const auto r3 = teIsDateInRange( first, last, d3 );

    BOOST_REQUIRE( r1 == -1 );
    BOOST_REQUIRE( r2 ==  0 );      // <--- line 30: fail
    BOOST_REQUIRE( r3 ==  1 );
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

This is the output of the test suite:

```
Running 1 test case...
main.cpp(30): fatal error in "test_case1": critical check r2 == 0 failed

*** 1 failure detected in test suite "timeext_test_unit"
```

A way to pass test is reimplement the function in this way but is not portable:

```
TMEXT_API int TMEXT_CALL teIsDateInRange( time_t firstDate, time_t lastDate, time_t date )
{
    if ( date < firstDate )
        return -1;

    if ( date > lastDate )
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Does someone know a portable way to check if a date is inside a range?

**edit** 
Another question the declaration of difftime is the following:

```
double difftime (time_t end, time_t beginning);
```

This seems to presume that end is bigger then beggining. In my situation I don't know if end is bigger than beggining.

Comment: The upper bound needs the opposite test that the lower bound does.  But you reversed the test *twice*.  Once in the `difftime` parameter order, and once in the result logic.

Comment: yes... it was a stupid errror, but `std::difftime` assumes that the first date is bigger than the second one. So this doesn't seems a safe way to compare two dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you check if date > lastDate and in that case you return 0:

```
// we are sure that date is greater then firstDate now check upper range
const auto diff2 = std::difftime( date, lastDate );
if ( diff2 >= 0.0 ) return 0;
```

You should return 0 if date < lastDate:

```
// we are sure that date is greater then firstDate now check upper range
const auto diff2 = std::difftime( date, lastDate );
if ( diff2 <= 0.0 ) return 0;
```

Comment: `std::difftime` assumes that the first date is bigger than the second one. So this doesn't seems a safe way to compare two dates

Comment: How about just comparing the raw values? `if ( date < lastDate ) return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Your second test returns 1 if `date < lastDate`. You want to return 1 if `date > lastDate`, i.e.

```
const auto diff2 = std::difftime( date, lastDate );
if ( diff2 > 0.0 ) return 1;
else return 0;
```